# how to pass data to another activity in recycler view by clicking a button outside the recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So, i've been working on this food delivery app. I want data from recycler view to another activity but on clicking the button that is not in recycler view, you can see that button is not inside the recycler view

```
package com.example.al_aham;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.room.Room;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.List;

public class myadapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myadapter.myviewholder>
{
    List<Product> products;
    Button checkout;
    TextView rateview;

    public myadapter(List<Product> products, TextView rateview) {
        this.products = products;
        this.rateview= rateview;

    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public myviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.singlerowdesign,parent,false);
        return new myviewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull myviewholder holder, int position) {



       holder.recid.setText(String.valueOf(products.get(position).getPid()));
       holder.recpname.setText(products.get(position).getPname());
       holder.recpprice.setText(String.valueOf(products.get(position).getPrice()));
       holder.recqnt.setText(String.valueOf(products.get(position).getQnt()));




       holder.delbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(holder.recid.getContext(),
               AppDatabase.class, "cart_db").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
               ProductDao productDao = db.ProductDao();

               productDao.deleteById(products.get(position).getPid());
               products.remove(position);
               notifyItemRemoved(position);
               updateprice();
           }
       });

        holder.incr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int qnt=products.get(position).getQnt();
                qnt++;
                products.get(position).setQnt(qnt);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                updateprice();
            }
        });

        holder.decr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int qnt=products.get(position).getQnt();
                qnt--;
                products.get(position).setQnt(qnt);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                updateprice();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    class myviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView recid,recpname,recqnt, recpprice;
        ImageButton delbtn;
        ImageView incr,decr;

        public myviewholder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            recid=itemView.findViewById(R.id.recid);
            recpname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.recpname);
            recpprice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.recpprice);
            recqnt=itemView.findViewById(R.id.recqnt);
            delbtn=itemView.findViewById(R.id.delbtn);
            incr=itemView.findViewById(R.id.incbtn);
            decr=itemView.findViewById(R.id.decbtn);
        }
    }

    public void updateprice()
    {
        int sum=0,i;
        for(i=0;i< products.size();i++)
            sum=sum+(products.get(i).getPrice()*products.get(i).getQnt());

        rateview.setText("Total Amount : INR "+sum);
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.al_aham;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.room.Room;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class cartdata extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<Product> products;
    RecyclerView recview;
    Button checkout;
    TextView rateview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cartdata);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        Button checkout = findViewById(R.id.checkout);
        products = new ArrayList<>();
        rateview=findViewById(R.id.rateview);

        getroomdata();

        checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(cartdata.this, Checkout.class);
                intent.putExtra("pname", products.get(1).getPname());
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        });



    }

    public void getroomdata()
    {
        AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                AppDatabase.class, "cart_db").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        ProductDao productDao = db.ProductDao();

        recview=findViewById(R.id.recview);
        recview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        List<Product> products=productDao.getallproduct();

        myadapter adapter=new myadapter(products, rateview);
        recview.setAdapter(adapter);

        int sum=0,i;
        for(i=0;i< products.size();i++)
            sum=sum+(products.get(i).getPrice()*products.get(i).getQnt());

        rateview.setText("Total Amount : INR "+sum);



    }



}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW9Uu.png)

I want use that to pass data to another activity by clicking that button

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(cartdata.this, Checkout.class);
intent.putExtra("list", products);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Checkout activity fetch data like this
ArrayList myList = getIntent ().getSerializableExtra("list");

Comment: Its not working can you explain this in more detail. Please

Comment: Are you getting any error? please share the error